# How to select last X records in SQL using Read-SqlTableData in Powershell

Tags: sql, powershell

So I'm writing a powershell script and utilizing the Module "sqlserver" to use the "Read-SqlTableData" cmdlet. I see there is a -topN X filter which selects from the top of the datatable but the way our table is set up, the oldest records at at the top but im trying to get newer records. Is there a way to select the last X records from the bottom?

This is what i have now. Any help is appreciated!

```
$SQLData=Read-SqlTableData -ServerInstance "Server" -Database "Database" -SchemaName "schema"  -tablename "table" -ColumnName "column","column2","column3"
```

Comment: See -columnOrder and -columnOrderType https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/read-sqltabledata?view=sqlserver-ps

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this, run a query and get the exact data you need.

```
try
{
    $ConnectionString = "Server=$($DatabaseServer);Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=$($DatabaseName)"
    $Query = "SELECT TOP $($BatchSize) * FROM [$($DatabaseName)].[dbo].[$($TableName)] WHERE $($colStatus) = 30"
    Write-Host "DEBUG: `$Query is $Query " -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
    $sqlConn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $sqlConn.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
    $sqlConn.Open()
    $sqlcmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $sqlcmd.Connection = $sqlConn
    $sqlcmd.CommandText = $Query
    $adp = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $sqlcmd
    $tbldata = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $adp.Fill($tbldata) | Out-Null 
    try {$sqlConn.Close()} catch {}
}
catch
{
    $errorMsg = "ERROR: Cannot connect to Database $DatabaseName using the following Connection String $ConnectionString. Query is $Query. Get-KLMigrationSQLData."
}

if ($tbldata)
{                
    Write-Host "DEBUG: Creating `$VDB Global Variable from Database Table: 
    $TableName" -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
    $dataFill = New-Variable -Name "VDB" -Force -PassThru -Scope Global
    $dataFill.Value = @()

    foreach ($DBRow in $tbldata.Tables.Rows)
    {
        $tempObj = New-Object System.Object
        $tempObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name TableName -Value $TableName 
        $DBRows = $DBRow | Get-Member | Where-Object {$_.MemberType -eq 'Property' -or $_.MemberType -eq 'ParameterizedProperty'} 
        ForEach ($Row in $DBRows){
            if ($Row.Name -ne 'Item')
            {
                $colName = $Row.Name
                $colValue = $DBRow.Item($colName)
                $tempObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name $colName -Value $colValue
            }
        } 
           $dataFill.Value += $tempObj
    }
}
```